# Vue.js render different form fields

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking for best practices for my task.

I have an API with a lot of questions and I need to build a front-end part to answer those. But these questions have different type of answers - text answer, choice answer, yes/no and stuff like that. So, depending on these types, I want to render different fields in my form.

The only way I know for now, is to do it using if-else but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something very similar to this recently. I added a field to the returned data that held a value for a "component" and just used a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

My example ended up looking like:

```
<component
  :is="subQuestion.component"
  :parentQuestion="question"
  :question="subQuestion" />
```